# Checking for empty strings

Tags: java

```
public static double convertWeight(String value, String value2) {
    double lbs = 0;
    double ounces = 0;
    if (!value.equals("")) {
        lbs = Double.parseDouble(value);
    }
    if (!value2.equals("")) {
        ounces = Double.parseDouble(value2) * 0.062500;
    }
    double grams = (lbs + ounces) / 0.0022046;
    return grams;
}
```

I have this piece of code, where at sometimes i get pounds or oz value `empty`. The above piece of code works fine, but i am not happy the way i have written the code. Can anyone tell me a better alternate way.

I have to `convertWeight`. So from my service i get sometimes values or sometimes just empty strings. If its empty i ensure that i pass lbs or ounces "`Zero`" `converWeight(value1, value2);`

Comment: Checking if the length is zero seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: For tips on improving functioning code, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: By the way, `java.lang.String` has an `isEmpty` method, which is the most idiomatic way to check if a string has length zero.

Comment: @ruakh: i am not using JDK 1.7, the project is getting compilied in 1.6 and also is it fine to have two if conditions....

Comment: First I would rename value and value2 to me more meaningful. Maybe sLbs or something.
Also the String.isEmpty is from Java 5.0.

Comment: @littlestewie no, that method exists on String already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 6 implemented a new String method, isEmpty().  As long as you're running 6 or above, you can rewrite your code using this method.  It's a bit more readable.

```
try {
    if (!isEmpty(value)) {
        lbs = Double.parseDouble(value);
    }
    if (!isEmpty(value2)) {
        ounces = Double.parseDouble(value2) * 0.062500;
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //Do some notification
    System.err.println("Invalid input.");
}
```

As an added suggestion .. You may want to wrap this code in a try/catch block.  If you don't, your program will crash with an uncaught exception if it tries to parse anything other than a valid double for either values.

Comment: Thanks, can u modify the code that i sent in try/catch, i am just getting some errors here when i try to do.

Comment: +1 for digging the fact that `.isEmpty()` was 1.6+ only! Wow, I have never had a second thought about using this method at all...

Comment: I actually had no idea it was implemented in 1.6 either before I researched to answer the question.  I got to learn something too.  :D

Comment: Also, theJava, I wrapped it in a try/catch block.  Naturally the System.err can be replaced with whatever you want to happen if it gets an invalid input.

Comment: THanks @EricWich, i tried to wrap the entire code in try/catch and since the method was excepting double, i was trying to return null if the try fails.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it this way

```
if (value != null && !value.trim().isEmpty())
```

- `Null` check to avoid an NPE
- Followed by a `trim()` to strip any extraneous spaces
- Followed by `isEmpty()` that returns true for length > 0

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Apache StringUtils.isEmpty(), .isNotEmpty(), .isBlank() and .isNotBlank(). Keeping Apache Commons around is useful for a lot of Java quirks, not just Strings.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

use `String.isEmpty` method

```
public static double convertWeight(String value, String value2) {
    double lbs = (value.isEmpty())?0:Double.parseDouble(value);
    double ounces = (value2.isEmpty())?0:Double.parseDouble(value2) * 0.062500;
    return (lbs + ounces) / 0.0022046;
}
```