# Difference between isEmpty() and zero length

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between these two methods?

```
public boolean nameControl(String str) 
{
    if (str.trim().isEmpty()) return false;
    if (str.trim().length() == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

I need find out that `str` should have at least one character.

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you looked at the source code? Have you looked at the javadoc?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it returns false

Comment: isEmpty() checks if the length of the String is 0

Comment: Nothing is different, only that one is explicitly checked where as isEmpty does the same under the hood.

Comment: Looks like about 5 characters worth of code space.

Comment: If your primary question is how to check whether a string is empty, then [Checking for empty strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16865521/1281433) is a possible duplicate.  You might also be interested in [Should I use string.isEmpty() or “”.equals(string)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3321526/1281433).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no real difference between them.

Javadocs for [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

> Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()):

> isEmpty
>
> public boolean isEmpty()
>
> Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.

Answer (score 4):

#### For Java 6+

`isEmpty()` works since **Java 6** and `length == 0` works since Java 1.2+ or possibly an older version.

If you notice, the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) of the method

#### Apache Commons Lang (for Java 5+)

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str)
```

of the class [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) use `str.length() == 0` in order to support Java 5.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you this is already documented:

IsEmpty():
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()

Length():
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect if a string has at least one (non-whitespace) character, I would try:

```
public boolean nameControl(String str) {
    if (str == null) return false;
    else if (str.trim().length() == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

If a string containing only whitespace should return true I would remove the `trim` as follows:

```
public boolean nameControl(String str) {
    if (str == null) return false;
    else if (str.length() == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: By definition, isn't any form of whitespace a character?

Comment: Based on the original posters use of trim, I had made the assumption that a string containing only whitespace should return false.  I have updated the answer to reflect both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to update on this:

> I Observed if the string is having newline char(\n or \r), that time
>   length fun gives you not zero value **but isEmpty fun standout with
>   value as true which is expected**.